# Django redirect() with additional parameters

Tags: python, django, django-views

Why is it that when I try to pass additional parameters, I get the error:

The below works fine! (Without parameters)

```
def first(request):
    return redirect('confirm')

def confirm(request):
    return render(request, 'template.html')
```

However this is what I need, which doesn't work as expected, and I get the error:

> Reverse for 'confirm' with keyword arguments '{'email': 'email'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['book/booking_confirmation/$']

```
def first(request):
    return redirect('confirm', email='some_email')

def confirm(request, email):
    return render(request, 'template.html', { 'email': email} )
```

*urls.py*

```
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^booking_confirmation/$', views.confirm, name='confirm'),
]
```

Comment: Well first of all, your first snippet would *not* work, because `redirect` does not expect a `request` parameter. And secondly, redirect is telling your browser to go to another URL. Does the confirm URL expect an `email` parameter?

Comment: Sorry I was just playing around trying to fix it and added `request`. If I remove it, I get error: Reverse for 'confirm' with keyword arguments '{'email': 'email'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['book/booking_confirmation/$']. Basically I wanted to have a personalised confirmation at the end, where it displays the fact we sent a confirmation to the email.

Comment: Well like I asked, does the URL for confirm expect an "email" parameter?

Comment: Oh, well this is the parameter I wanted to pass from the `first` function. Maybe this is not how it works. I wanted to pass the email from `first()` to the view rendered by `confirm()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't want to pass the email via the URL in the redirect, it may be easiest to store it in the session.

```
def first(request):
    request.session['email'] = 'some_email'
    return redirect('confirm')

def confirm(request):
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'email': request.session['email']})
```

Comment: wow, I didn't expect that kind of 'trick'. Thanks

Comment: Brilliant, saved my day. Nice one.

Answer (score 2):

Configure the url pattern to capture the email. *e.g.*

```
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^booking_confirmation/(?P<email>\w+)$', views.confirm, name='confirm'),
]
```

You can use more robust pattern-match for the captured email instead of capturing only word characters.

Comment: This is what I need, but without having the email value in the url, is that possible?

Comment: What _Will Keeling_ said